# How to customize TabBar (TabLayout) in different page - xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is it possible to implement `app:tabMode="scrollable"` in specific page only? I have 2 page that contains TabBar and the other one should be in fixed mode only.

I created a custom TabBar and in Android and it is deployed on all my TabBar page.

My customTabBar.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="80dp"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="#FF3300"  
    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/CustomTab" 
    app:tabMode="scrollable" />
```

And for my MainActivity.cs

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        AppCompatDelegate.DefaultNightMode = AppCompatDelegate.ModeNightNo;

        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.CustomTabbar; 

        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
```

Comment: Since the app:tabMode="scrollable"` is set for TabLayout , it should be affect all the TabbedPage. `the other one should be in fixed mode only.` Why do you want different effects in different tabbedpages?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT I have 2 layout. 1st tabbpage has only 3 tabs and it is not taking full width, instead they are all in left side. 2nd tabbpage 5 tabs and that's fine which fits the whole mobile screen.

Comment: `1st tabbpage has only 3 tabs and it is not taking full width, instead they are all in left side.`   How can they only in the left side? Could you please post more details about this?